# Version 2 of AutoHotkey. how do I use the Ctrl and Z keys to perform the action of pressing the p key after right mouse click?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

Version 2 of AutoHotkey. how do I use the Ctrl and Z keys to perform the action of pressing the p key after right mouse click?

I tried, but the code gives me an error.

```
<^z::+F10 & p
```

OS
windows10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Send`

```
<^z::SendInput, +{F10}p
```

or

```
<^z::SendInput, {RButton}p
```

Comment: It worked as expected. thank you very much.